# Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error() method is not working Inside a Static Class

Tags: logging, error-handling

I typically do my error logging like this:

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("My Error Message Here", ex, this);
```

But, that same syntax does not work for inside a Static class since `this` is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer.

I see from the IntelliSense that my other options would be `string loggerName` or `Type ownerType`. But, I'm not sure exactly what these options mean.

What is the correct way to log an error inside a static class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, recommended practice would be to use a `Namespace` as your logger, as opposed to `new object()` or anything else.  Just using "YourLoggerName" would not be flexible enough to allow admins to fine tune log handling inside your module.

As you rightly point out, `this` will not work in a static class. But this will:

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Message", ex, typeof(YourStaticClass));
```

Which is the exact equivalent of `this`.

Comment: I agree, this is the way. The type is what determines which log file to write to.

Comment: How about for a static function?

Comment: A static function would still live in a static class, and logging usually does not register on method level. `this` also refers to just the class name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of a string for the object parameter as shown below:

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Message", ex, "YourLoggerName");
```

The `loggerName` is the module or feature. For example, you are using the `Log.Error` in the module Product, you can set the loggerName as Product. This can be useful when you see the errors with the logger as Product, which means it is being triggered in the Product Module.

The `ownerType` is a type. For example `PropertyLayout`, `ExceptionLayout` are different ownerType

**What is the correct way to log an error inside a static class?**

It all depends what you want to retrieve when you check the logs. Normally, you will make use of the `Log.Error` in your modules. So, it will be preferable to use the following:

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Message", ex, "YourLoggerName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object (instance of a class), like below:

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Message", ex, new object());
```

`this` does not work, as the the `Error()` or any other logging method expects an instance of class, so it won't work in static method.

Comment: While this will work, better practice is use typeof(YourStaticClass) - if you ever define a dedicated log file for your own assemblies in future, it'll work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a singleton rather than creating a static class.  This should allow you to use "this."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: I'd suggest to create a 'regular' class and _register_ it as a Singleton using ether Sitecore DI (8.2+) or Sitecore Factory.